# How to Data Scrape from multiple pages

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

```
import os
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.page_load_strategy = 'eager'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
url = "https://www.moneycontrol.com/financials/marutisuzukiindia/ratiosVI/MS24#MS24"
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
```

I want to find the value of cash EPS (standalone as well as consolidated) but the main problem is, only 5 values are on the page and other values are retrieved with the arrow button till it ends.

How to retrieve such values in one go?

Comment: how about pressing that button? probably can't unless they are already loaded or You have access to their database which renders this method useless in the first place

Comment: yes but how to know when final value exist because button still exist on that page too.

Comment: @Matiiss No, dont have access to database, so need to scrap from webpage only

Comment: well press the button until You don't get any values anymore

Comment: Thats what I want to know how to know that its of pressing because it wont load any page after last value

Comment: well try reading all values and when a value returns nothing stop pressing or if the program starts reading the same again just check against the previous and if match stop

Comment: No better option we do have?

Comment: not that I would know, maybe someone more knowing in these processes will come by and help You otherwise I can't really tell anything more than I have already

Comment: this is a paging element, it's getting href as "javascript:void();" once click are over paging count. If data is still there its has a paging # number there(refer 4 in this case). https://www.moneycontrol.com/financials/marutisuzukiindia/ratiosVI/MS24/4#MS24. So any one condition can be used for the exit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking my comment further to the code.
Comment:
this is a paging element, it's getting href as "javascript:void();" once click are over paging count. If data is still there its has a paging # number there(refer 4 in this case). moneycontrol.com/financials/marutisuzukiindia/ratiosVI/MS24/…. So any one condition can be used for the exit!

comment in code refers to the suggestion.

```
df_list=pd.read_html(driver.page_source) # read the table through pandas
result=df_list[0] #load the result, which will be eventually appended for next pages.

current_page=driver.find_element_by_class_name('nextpaging') # find elment of span 
while True:
    current_page.click()
    time.sleep(20) # sleep for 20 
    current_page=driver.find_element_by_class_name('nextpaging')
    paging_link = current_page.find_element_by_xpath('..') # get the parent of this span which has the href
    print(f"Currentl url : { driver.current_url } Next paging link : { paging_link.get_attribute('href')} ")
    if "void" in paging_link.get_attribute('href'):
        print(f"Time to exit {paging_link.get_attribute('href')}")
        break # exit rule 

    df_list=pd.read_html(driver.page_source)
    result=result.append(df_list[0]) # append the result
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on looking at the URL while navigating through this sight

```
https://www.moneycontrol.com/financials/marutisuzukiindia/ratiosVI/MS24/1#MS24
```

It appears the arrows navigate to a new URL, incrementing a number in the URL in front of the `#` symbol.

so, navigating through pages looks like this:

```
Page1: https://www.moneycontrol.com/financials/marutisuzukiindia/ratiosVI/MS24/1#MS24
Page2: https://www.moneycontrol.com/financials/marutisuzukiindia/ratiosVI/MS24/2#MS24
Page3: https://www.moneycontrol.com/financials/marutisuzukiindia/ratiosVI/MS24/3#MS24
etc...
```

these separate urls can be used to navigate through this particular website. Probably this would work

```
def get_pg_url(pgnum):
    return 'https://www.moneycontrol.com/financials/marutisuzukiindia/ratiosVI/MS24/{}#MS24'.format(pgnum)
```

web scraping requires tuning to fit the target sight. I entered `pgnum=10000`, which resulted in the text `Data Not Available for Key Financial Ratios` being displayed. You can probably us this text to tell you when there are no remaining pages.

Comment: Thats what my problem was, how to know that next page loading has been ended. Will try this,